# How can I query VSAM data from Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, vsam

Is there a way (JDBC, Resource Adapter, etc) to query VSAM data from Java?  Do solutions require something be installed on the VSAM system?

If JDBC, what limitations exist on the SQL allowed?

Answer (score 3):

One answer I've found in searching is the IBM VSE Connector, which seems to have JDBC support with at least rudimentary metadata and SQL access:

ftp://ftp.boulder.ibm.com/s390/zos/vse/pdf3/vse27/ieswue30.pdf

This solution requires you to install the VSE Connector Server on the VSAM side.

Answer (score 3):

Alex, that would only work for VSE - for the high-end (i.e. z/OS, nee OS/390, nee MVS/ESA, nee...) what I think you might find useful is the API from the JZOS Toolkit (Free! - a rarity from IBM...) that supplies native methods for accessing most basic mainframe access methods (i.e. sequential, partitioned, VSAM, etc.).

Links that may be helpful:

- [Java Stand-alone Applications on z/OS, Volume I](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247177.html)
- [Java Stand-alone Applications on z/OS, Volume II](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247291.html)

If you want anything more specific, I would be glad to help (esp. if it was Clojure related...).